# How to use $\binom a k = \frac{\alpha(a-1)(a-2)\cdots(a-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots 1}$ to check that ${-1\choose 0}=1$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to use the binomial coefficient:

$$\binom{x}k=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^{\underline k}}{k!},&\text{if }k\ge 0\\\\
0,&\text{if }k<0\;,
\end{cases}$$

To check that ${-1\choose 0}=1$. But it doesn't make sense. I'm using, specifically:

$$\binom a k = \frac{\alpha(a-1)(a-2)\cdots(a-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots 1}$$

Then I guess it would be:

$${-1 \choose 0}=\frac{(-1)(-1-0)}{0(?)}$$

The denominator should be a product of decreasing numbers from $k$ to $1$, but it's impossible to decrease from $0$ to $1$. At this point, I'm not sure if something can be made with this definition to make it work or if I should assume that $0!=1.$

Comment: 0! = 1 by definition

Comment: I just need to do that? There's nothing that could be made with that definition so that it would result in ${-1 \choose 0}=1$?

Comment: yes, use the falling factorial definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\binom{x}{k} = \frac
{\prod ~\{x - 0,~ x - 1,~ x - 2,~ \dots,~ x - (k-1)\}}
{\prod~ \{k - 0,~ k - 1,~ k - 2,~ \dots,~ k - (k-1)\}}$$

When $k$ is $0$, this becomes the quotient of the products of empty sets:

$$\binom{x}{0} = \frac
{\prod~ \{\}}
{\prod~ \{\}}$$

And the product of the elements of an empty set is better defined as $1$, so

$$\binom{x}{0} = \frac
{\prod~ \{\}}
{\prod~ \{\}} = \frac 11 = 1$$