# On ${-1 \choose 0}=1$, can I assume that $\frac{(-1)!}{(-1)!}=1$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I've had to evaluate ${-1 \choose0}$ and then I discovered the following:

$${-1 \choose0}=\frac{(-1)!}{(-1)!0!}=\frac{(-1)!}{(-1)!}=1$$

Can I assume that $\frac{(-1)!}{(-1)!}=1$?

Comment: Doesn't the gamma function have a simple pole at $-1$?

Comment: @graydad I still don't know about the gamma function.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've had to evaluate $\binom{-1}{0}$"? If that appeared in a formula you applied, you very probably applied the formula in the wrong way.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Yes, it appeared in a formula. But the propositions in the books I've read work with it perfectly. I'm reading a brazilian book on combinatorics and I also read a bit of Knuth/Patashnik/Graham's *Concrete Mathematics.* Im both books, they appear to make sense, the latter book even discusses about it.

Comment: related: [How to use $\binom a k = \frac{\alpha(a-1)(a-2)\cdots(a-k+1)}{k(k-1)(k-2)\cdots 1}$ to check that ${-1\choose 0}=1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082238/how-to-use-binom-a-k-frac-alphaa-1a-2-cdotsa-k1kk-1k-2-cdots)

Comment: @GrigoryM Not, it is not. It's a completely different question, read both and check it. At that question, I asked **how to use the definition to check that**, in this question, I'm askinf **if I could assume that $\frac{(-1)!}{(-1)!}=1$**.

Comment: @Vÿska The gamma function is a function that can be used to calculate factorial of non-positive integer numbers. Although all the negative integers are undefined. At this point the question reminds me of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}=1$ but GrigoryM has linked a question that may help you

Comment: @graydad Yes. I am the one who made the question pointed by GrigroyM, but I am trying to look at it with a different intention.

Comment: @GrigoryM See [here](http://i.imgur.com/MG0SP4q.png). Excerpt from Knuth/Patashnik/Graham's *Concrete Mathematics*, page 154.

Comment: @GrigoryM although gamma function has poles there, you still can take the limit of $a\to-1$ and get $1$.

Comment: OK, I apologise — this question was not completely clear as written — but it's a) not a duplicate of the linked question; b) can be reasonably answered.

Comment: @GrigoryM Nevermind. Did you see what I suggested? That's what's leaving me a little bit confused.

Answer (score 2):

From the definition of the binomial coefficients we can generalize to negative numbers by applying the following method,
\begin{align}\binom{-n}{k} &= \frac{-n\cdot-(n+1)\dots-(n+k-2)\cdot-(n+k-1)}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\;\frac{n\cdot(n+1)\cdot(n+2)\cdots (n + k - 1)}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{n + k - 1}{k}\\
&=(-1)^k\left(\!\!\binom{n}{k}\!\!\right)\;.
\end{align}

And by putting $n=1$ and $k=0$, the answer to your query is yes

Comment: What is the meaning of $\displaystyle \left( {n \choose k}\right)$?

Comment: @Vÿska Just the multiset notation meaning a rising factorial $(e.g., n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+k-1)$ rather than a falling one.

Answer (score 2):

Since $n!$ is infinite or undefined for negative integers, it is not really proper to use factorial on negative integers. However, there are a couple of ways to attempt to work around this problem.

We can consider $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$ and consider points very close to integers. This approach needs to be used with care. For example:
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{-1}{0}
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\Gamma(h)}{\Gamma(h)\Gamma(1)}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac1h\Gamma(1+h)}{\frac1h\Gamma(1+h)\Gamma(1)}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\Gamma(1+h)}{\Gamma(1+h)\Gamma(1)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1)}\\[6pt]
&=1\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
However, if we change the approach to the limit point, things fall apart:
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{-1}{0}
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\Gamma(2h)}{\Gamma(h)\Gamma(1+h)}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\frac1{2h}\Gamma(1+2h)}{\frac1h\Gamma(1+h)\Gamma(1+h)}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac12\frac{\Gamma(1+2h)}{\Gamma(1+h)\Gamma(1)}\\
&=\frac12\frac{\Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1)}\\
&=\frac12\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
This is because
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(y+1)\Gamma(x-y+1)}\tag{3}
$$
is not continuous at $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ when $x\lt0$. However, if we fix $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, then we get
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to-n}f(x,m)
&=\lim_{x\to-n}\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(m+1)\Gamma(x-m+1)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-n}\frac{\frac1{x+1}\frac1{x+2}\cdots\frac1{x+n}\Gamma(x+n+1)}{\Gamma(m+1)\frac1{x-m+1}\frac1{x-m+2}\cdots\frac1{x+n}\Gamma(x+n+1)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to-n}\frac{(x-m+1)(x-m+2)\cdots x}{\Gamma(m+1)}\\
&=\frac{(-n)(-n-1)\cdots(-n-m+1)}{m!}\\
&=(-1)^m\binom{n+m-1}{m}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
which is the proper value given by the binomial theorem. Thus, we can consider the binomial coefficients as ratios of Gamma functions, but only if we approach along the proper path.

To address your question a bit more directly, $\frac{(-1)!}{(-1)!}=\frac{\Gamma(0)}{\Gamma(0)}$ *should* be equal to both $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{\Gamma(2h)}{\Gamma(h)}$ and $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{\Gamma(h)}{\Gamma(h)}$, but these limits are different. Therefore, not only because we are dealing with $\frac\infty\infty$, but also because these limits do not exist in general, it might be best to avoid $\frac{(-1)!}{(-1)!}$.